# Magento1.7's native captcha for contacts us form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I want to use magento's native captcha for contacts-us page. If I use other extension's captcha, then it will looking like dirt to see, different captcha's for different forms in a single website. For login page, checkout as guest we use native captcha. But how can I use native captcahf for contactus page also???

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this recent post. I had a look around for the same issue and most treads only offered core hacks.
This one seems good as you're creating a module to add the form into the normal admin menu etc.
[blog link from various Mag forum treads](http://razbakov.com/en/magento-native-captcha-for-contact-form/)

Comment: I have seen this blog. In that they have mentioned for magento enterprise 1.12 version. I am using magento CE 1.7 version.  I am not sure whether this can be done with this or not.So only I havent tried this. If I try this for product review-form then, I dont have idea what to mention there in the place of contacts.xml. So can u suggest me what I can mention in that place??

Comment: there is a 'review.xml' under app > design > frontend > base > default > layout, which you can work off. And under app > design > frontend > base > default > template > review you have the templates to work from. I have tried this yet, but it does look like a thorough tutorial